# Perl File Write Issue

Tags: perl

I'm having a really weird problem with this perl script.  The basic point is that *sometimes* a file write/append doesn't happen.  On a run of the program, either all of the writes will happen or none of them will.  Here is the subroutine, with some comments:

```
sub process_svs {
  my $F;
  open($F, '<', $_[0]);
  if($log_dups==1) {
    open($dfh, '>>',"./duplicates.txt");
  }
  while (my $line = <$F>) {
    chomp $line;
    if($line =~ /somepattern/) {
      if (! -e "somefile") {
        copy("source","dest") or warn ("couldn't copy");
      } elsif($log_dups==1) {
        system("touch ./duplicates.txt"); # ghetto workaround
        print $dfh "./".$_[0]."_files/".$1.",v already exists\n" or die("Couldn't write duplicate"); # problem line
      }
    }
  }
  close $F;
}
```

The print statements to stdout always work, but if I remove the `touch ./duplicates.txt` crap, nothing is written to `duplicates.txt`.

The other "weird" thing, is that earlier in the program, I create a directory with perl `mkdir`, and if the directory exists when the program is run, I **don't** need the workaround, the duplicates.txt writing works just fine.  If I delete the directory, and let the program `mkdir` it, it doesn't work.  Seems relevant, but I can't figure out how since the directory and the text file are not in the same location, or related in *any* way, that I can think of.

Additionally, I have run it through the debugger, and can see the write call being executed, but inspecting duplicates.txt immediately after the write shows nothing written.

Any possible reasons for this would be greatly appreciated.

If you want to see a modified, but more complete, version of the script, it is here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;
my $svs = $ARGV[0];
my $rhis_str = system("rhis $svs > ./tmp_history");
my $fh;
my $dfh;
my @versions;
my $all_revs = 0;
my $current_rev = "";
my $log_dups = 0;
sub process_svs {
  my $F;
  open($F, '<', $_[0]);
  if($log_dups==1) {
    open($dfh, '>>',"./duplicates.txt");
  }
  while (my $line = <$F>) {
    chomp $line;
    if($line =~ /something/) {
      if (! -e "something") {
        copy("source","dest") or warn ("couldn't copy ");
      } elsif($log_dups==1) {
        system("touch ./duplicates.txt"); # ghetto workaround
        print $dfh "something already exists\n" or die("Couldn't write duplicate");
      }
    }
  }
  close $F;
}
for(my $i = 0; $i <= scalar @ARGV; $i++) {
  my $arg = $ARGV[$i];
  if($arg eq "-a") {
    $all_revs = 1;
  } elsif($arg eq "-r") {
    $all_revs = 0;
    $current_rev = $ARGV[$i+1];
  } elsif($arg eq "--log-dups") {
    $log_dups = 1;
  }
}
open($fh, '<','./tmp_history') or die(">>> Failed to open ./tmp_history");;
mkdir "./".$svs."_files";
if($all_revs == 1) {
  print ">>> Processing all revisions of ".$svs;
  if($log_dups==1) {
    print" (and logging duplicates)\n";
  }
  while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /something/) {
      push @versions, $1;
    }
  }
}
  system("some_cmd &>/dev/null");
  process_svs($svs);
}
```

Comment: `while (my $line = ) {` doesn't compile.

Comment: I edited out some context-specific things, maybe I made a mistake somewhere? I don't see the issue with `while (my $line = <$F>) {` though, and even if it is wrong, it is not relevant to the problem I'm having, I don't think.

Comment: You need to show a snip of your input. Also, use three-arg open, with exception: `open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "can't open $file: $!";`

Comment: `use strict;` and `use warnings;` should be present at the top of your script as well.

Comment: The snippet posted is a small portion of the script.  `use strict` and `use warnings` are both there.

Comment: show input so it can be tested.

Comment: I've added a more complete version, but it is still slimmed down to remove some unnecessary detail.

Comment: As stevieb already mentioned, you *really* should check the result of `open`.  You can do it the way he shows, or you can add `use autodie` at the top of the script to automatically check.

Comment: That makes sense, and is certainly good practice, and I will add that check, however, even if there is a problem opening the file, the first time it tries a write it will fail, and there is a `die` there.  It also doesn't explain why `touch`ing the file serves as a workaround, since the open call will have already taken place by the time the write and touch will have happened.

Comment: What operating system and filesystem is this on? Windows has some odd mandatory file locking issues that could be causing the problem.

Comment: You have a trailing `}` at the end of your code.  Make *really sure* you're showing us the real code.

Comment: @Schwern sorry, I assumed the /dev/null gave away the fact that it's a Linux flavor.  I would post the entire code if I could, but in this case I need to remove some context, so it's possible I made a mistake while trying to sanitize the code.

Answer (score 4):

You're not checking to see if your files opened.  This is a very, very basic mistake and you should fix this immediately.  Either add `or die $!` after each `open` or, better yet, `use autodie` and it will take care of catching all IO exceptions for you and give you good, consistent error messages.

Most importantly, this will tell you *why* it failed to open.  `$!` tells you *why* it failed.  You don't have that in your check on `print`.

```
    print $dfh "./".$_[0]."_files/".$1.",v already exists\n" or die("Couldn't write duplicate"); # problem line
```

You're checking if `print` failed, but you're not including `$!`.  Either add `$!` like `die "Couldn't write to duplicate: $!"` or `use autodie`, remove the `or die` clause, and let autodie take care of it.  I recommend the second.

I suspect you'll find that something else is deleting `duplicates.txt` between the open and the print.

---

The second thing that grabs my attention is here.

```
if($log_dups==1) {
  open($dfh, '>>',"./duplicates.txt");
}
```

You're using a global variable `$log_dups` to decide whether or not to open the file for writing (and not checking if it succeeded).  This should be a variable that gets passed into the function, it's just good programming practice.  Later you decide whether to print to `$dfh` based on that global variable.

```
  if (! -e "something") {
    copy("source","dest") or warn ("couldn't copy ");
  } elsif($log_dups==1) {
    system("touch ./duplicates.txt"); # ghetto workaround
    print $dfh "something already exists\n" or die("Couldn't write duplicate");
  }
```

Because `$log_dups` is global it's possible something else is changing `$log_dups` between deciding to open `duplicates.txt` and writing to it.  To avoid all these problems, and to make the code simpler, `$log_dups` should be an argument passed into the function.

---

Furthermore, the filehandle `$dfh` is inexplicably a global.  Same problem, something else could be closing it.  It will also not be automatically closed at the end of the function which might leave writes to `duplicates.txt` buffered until the program exits.  `$dfh` should be a lexical.

---

Other problems...

```
my $rhis_str = system("rhis $svs > ./tmp_history");
```

`$rhis_str` will contain the exit status of the `rhis` program.  I don't think that's what you want.  You don't use this variable anyway.

---

There's no need to pass `./file` to `open`, it's safe and easier to read to use just pass `file`.  That it's in the current working directory is implied.

---

If you fix these basic problems and still have trouble, then edit your question with the revised code and we can look again.

Comment: this is a nice dissection.

Comment: Ditto. Always check to see if your files are opened: `open($dfh, '>>',"./duplicates.txt") or die "Could not open duplicates.txt. $!";` Also, this file $dfh will only open if $log_dups==1. You need an else statement after that to print a message if $log_dups != 1.

Comment: @prelic It was not my intent to condescend, I held my comments to only the code and only the aspects that could cause your problem. If you point out the parts you find objectionable I'll consider changing them.